# Jsonapi query to return specific field

Tags: 8

In a simple article content type, is there a way we can have a jsonapi query to return specific field only? The same as how REST export view is doing, we can select what field to be displayed in the output.

E.g. `http://localhost:8080/jsonapi/node/article/<return body field value>`

If not, is there a method I can create a list of string then I would want to call a jsonapi to get that list. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the caveat it still contains the JSONAPI document payload around your requested field. This is mandated by the spec so you can't just have an arbitrary JSON structure that contains **only** the field data you want.

This is called a sparse fields query. When you add a `?fields[$RESOURCE_ENTITY]=field1,field2...` to a:

- index endpoint (`/jsonapi/node/article`)
- resource endpoint (`/jsonapi/node/article/$UUID`) endpoint

It will trim down the list of fields to the comma-delimited list you've specified.

To use your example, `http://localhost:8080/jsonapi/node/article?fields[node--article]=body` will return a JSONAPI document with all `article` nodes with only the `body` property in the `attributes` object.

See the JSONAPI docs about [fetching resources](https://www.drupal.org/node/2806623) for more info.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried it and seems to be displaying the field I want, but it generates other details I dont need. Basically I just want to get a simple result, say
`[
  "DOG",
  "CAT",
  "RAT"
]`