# Other way to create a list of string other than taxonomies

Tags: 8

Is there a method in Drupal to create s list of string dynamically and I would want to use a jsonapi to call it.

Expected output in jsonapi:

```
[
  "DOG",
  "CAT",
  "RAT"
]
```

When I added new string value, then it will be added in the top list of the api result

According to the answer on my previous thread in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/269610/70281, it mentions:

> To use your example,
>   http://localhost:8080/jsonapi/node/article?fields[node--article]=body
>   will return a JSONAPI document with all article nodes with only the
>   body property in the attributes object.

But the output is a bit noisy.

```
{"data":[{"type":"node--symbols","id":"77d69b2e-ed9c-4173-b933-af89f634ba79","attributes":{"field_symbols":"EURUSD"},"links":{"self":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/jsonapi\/node\/symbols\/77d69b2e-ed9c-4173-b933-af89f634ba79"}},{"type":"node--symbols","id":"dac4124d-9311-49b8-bd14-1fa5df2fc937","attributes":{"field_symbols":"EURGBP"},"links":{"self":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/jsonapi\/node\/symbols\/dac4124d-9311-49b8-bd14-1fa5df2fc937"}}],"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0","meta":{"links":{"self":"http:\/\/jsonapi.org\/format\/1.0\/"}}},"links":{"self":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/jsonapi\/node\/symbols?fields%5Bnode--symbols%5D=field_symbols"}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically'? What sort of triggers change the output of the list?

Comment: @Darvanen thanks for your interest to my concern. Regarding to your question, it should not be a static list of string. Say if I want to add a new value, then it will just be added, and would also reflect into the api. Same how taxonomy term functions, we also want to make it as a reference field but we dont want a look up table. So just a basic list of strings.

Comment: If the noise in the JSON response is your only issue then I would use a taxonomy and create a [custom JSON response](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/custom-restful-api-drupal-8) that loads the taxonomy and lists out the terms. If that sounds like a reasonable approach I can provide a bit more detail in time.

Comment: that is my current implementation, I am using a taxonomy terms, however, we want to avoid look up tables, since we are implementing other external services in calling these values. But if you mean that if I will use taxonomy, then in my custom json response, it will just output a list of taxonomy termnames? Then, that is a good approach for me. I am not interested in the term ID, we want to directly access the term name. Thank you!

Comment: I think the solution will still be uising the taxonomy terms. And how I get a good  json response, I use the REST export view, and there I can select which field I will be displaying.

Comment: Yes, that does sound like a good solution :)